# Veach's thesis, projected solid angle sanity check

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, absolute-value, solid-angle

Here's an equivalence from Veach's thesis on light transport (page 88, 3.16):
$$|\cos(\theta)|\sin(\theta)d(\theta)d(\phi) \equiv \\
 \sin(\theta)d(\sin(\theta))d(\phi)$$

This seems wrong in the general case since the absolute value is dropped. Also, $\theta$ is assumed to be in $[0,\pi]$ (as can be seen in 3.17), so this definitely doesn't seem like it can be done. I just want somebody to confirm that this is indeed a typo. The thesis can be found here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/veach_thesis/

P.S. I have no idea how to change the name of the link, tried [url] and < a >.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *does* look like a typo to me, at least for $\omega \cdot N < 0$; for the case where you're studying scattering *by reflection*, however, it might be useful.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote you sadly. Note that below that equivalence, he has 2 additional such (which assume that cos(theta) is positive), which is even stranger. Also, I've never seen a notation such as d!, which really needs to be -d in this case. Maybe a LaTeX error that messed up everything after?

Comment: I wondered about the $d!$ as well; I think it's *not* an error -- Veach is pretty good with this stuff. In general, the whole dissertation is a treasure. One warning: most integrals are Lesbegue integrals with respect to some measure, and I sometimes find myself confused about the exact measure being used.

Comment: I'll try to look into my references to find the d! notation, since google proved ineffective. I am fine with Lebesgue integrals and measure theory. Only this part kept bugging me about the absolute value. And the thesis is truly a treasure trove. Thank you for your feedback, I asked other people too, and they all seem to agree with your conclusion.

Comment: As I think about it, $d\sin\theta$ probably doesn't make sense as a (Lesbegue) measure when $\cos \theta < 0$; I wonder whether there's some hidden convention we're both unaware of? :)